# "No suitable method found for sort(List<VarStatusMsg<? extends Number>>)" JDK error

Tags: java, ant

I encountered the following error when running an Ant build on my Java source code:

```
[javac] /home/path/to/my/java/function/VarStatusLog.java:28: error: no suitable method found for sort(List<VarStatusMsg<? extends Number>>)
[javac]         Collections.sort(logMsg);
[javac]                    ^
[javac]     method Collections.<T#1>sort(List<T#1>) is not applicable
[javac]       (inference variable T#1 has incompatible bounds
[javac]         equality constraints: VarStatusMsg<? extends Number>
[javac]         upper bounds: VarStatusMsg<CAP#1>,Comparable<? super T#1>)
[javac]     method Collections.<T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>) is not applicable
[javac]       (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
[javac]         (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
[javac]   where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
[javac]     T#1 extends Comparable<? super T#1> declared in method <T#1>sort(List<T#1>)
[javac]     T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>)
[javac]   where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
[javac]     CAP#1 extends Number from capture of ? extends Number
```

I use JDK 1.8 with my Ant builds. Note that Eclipse on Windows does not throw errors but when I run from a command line on Linux, I get the error. Anybody can help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I'd say `VarStatusMsg` does not implement the interface `Comparable<VarStatusMsg>`. The signature of the `sort` method you are using is `public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)`. Either make your `VarStatusMsg` implement the interface `Comparable<VarStatusMsg>`, or give a `Comparator<VarStatusMsg>` as second argument to `sort`.

Btw. you can simply call `logMsg.sort(null)` instead of `Collections.sort(logMsg)` or `logMsg.sort(myNiceComparator)` instead of `Collections.sort(logMsg, myNiceComparator)`. The `Collections` methods only delegate to `List` nowadays.

Comment: Thanks. Would the above code have worked had i compiled it on JDK 1.6?

Comment: Nope, Generics are in place since 1.5. Up to 1.4 the code would have compiled, but thrown a `ClassCastException` at runtime.